# iphone, multiple uiwindows in one iphone application

Tags: iphone, uiview, interface-builder, uiwindow

hi
I am an iphone newbie, so a little confused in UIWindow concept. On Mac, we can use multiple NSWindows in one application, i guess. But in iphone, can we use multiple UIWindows in one iphone application. To be very specific, i have 3 xib files in my application:
1. MainWindow.xib
2. ViewController (coupled with appDelegate)
3. MyCustomViewController... wherein i want to use UIwindow and multiple views with that window.

Now my question is that i am already using UIWindow in MainWindow.xib, can i use use another UIWindow in MyCustomeViewController.xib???

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use another window just keep swapping views on the available UIWindow & you'll be fine.

Comment: That is fine... but plz can you explain a little how do i do that?

Comment: Okay.. on Iphone we have a very limited screen real estate unlike the desktop... Though I think you can create multiple instances of UIWindow if you want but usually the best practice is to use just one UIWindow...  Application Programming guide in the docs states the same.......

Comment: I've created a view and added to UIwindow as [UIWindow addSubview:myView], but later on i create another view and want to add that to UIWindow...(In some other class). So in another class, i get an instance of applicatoin delegate with [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; and add another view to that... and then use [[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] but my other doesn't appear in UIWindow... How do i do that plz???  I think it may be a very weired question,.. but sorry

Answer (score 3):

You don't need and shouldn't use several windows on iPhone according to the documentation.

What you need is to change view controllers currently present on the screen.

From you ViewController you can take to ways to present MyCustomViewController:
1. Employ UINavigationController's method  - (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated if case you put your ViewController inside a navigation controller.

1. Use - (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated method of UIViewController class.

something like below inside you ViewController methods:

```
MyCustomViewController *vc = [MyCustomViewController new];
[self presentModalViewController: vc animated: YES];
[vc release];
```

see "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS" for exhaustive discussion: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not the standard approach for iOS apps.

If you still want to do it see this answer

[Advantages, problems, examples of adding another UIWindow to an iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232398/advantages-problems-examples-of-adding-another-uiwindow-to-an-ios-app/15879624#15879624)