# Advantages, problems, examples of adding another UIWindow to an iOS app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiwindow

Recently I've been wondering about the fact that that an iOS app only has one `UIWindow`.
It does not seem to be an issue to create another `UIWindow` and place it on screen.

My question is kind of vague, but I'm interested in:

- What could I potentially achieve with a second `UIWindow` that cannot be done in other ways?
- What can go wrong when using multiple `UIWindow` instances?
- I have seen that people use a 2nd `UIWindow` to display popover like views on iPhone. Is this a good way of doing it? Why? Why not?
- Are there other examples where it is making perfectly sense to have another `UIWindow`?

It's not that I'm missing something. I have never felt the need to create another `UIWindow` instance but maybe it would allow doing amazing things I'm not aware of! :-)

I'm hoping that it might help me solve this problem:
I need to add a "cover view" over whatever is currently displayed. It should also work if there are already one or more modal controllers presented. If I add a `UIView` to the root controller's view, the modal controllers sit on top, so do the popover controllers.
If I present the cover view modally and there is already a modal controller, only part of the screen is covered.

Comment: Using multiple UIWindows in iOS applications http://shaune.com.au/using-multiple-uiwindows-in-ios-applications/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A `UIWindow` can float above other UI elements like the system keyboard.

To address your last paragraph: Make a `UIWindow` with the same frame as your main window.  Set its `windowLevel` property to `UIWindowLevelStatusBar`.  Set its `hidden` property to `NO`.

Comment: Err, alright. Thanks. I knew that. Can you get a bit into detail wrt my questions? Do you know how to get RID of a seconds UIWindow that was added by makeKeyAndVisible?

Comment: Set the second UIWindow's hidden property to YES.

Comment: Thanks. And I show the window by making it key and visible? And I hide it by making ANOTHER window visible and just disposing the other one? How can I animate a UIWindow like UIActionSheet does it?

Comment: Be careful with this. If at != UIWindowLevelNormal, the keyboard will show underneath it on < iOS7.

Answer (score 112):

Starting with Rob's answer I played around a bit and would like to write down some notes for others trying to get information on this topic:

- It is not a problem at all to add another `UIWindow`. Just create one and `makeKeyAndVisible`. Done.
- Remove it by making another window visible, then release the one you don't need anymore.
- The window that is "key" receives all the keyboard input.
- `UIWindow` covers everything, even modals, popovers, etc. Brilliant!
- `UIWindow` is always portrait implicitly. It does no rotate. You'll have to add a controller as the new window's root controller and let that handle rotation. (Just like the main window)
- The window's level determines how "high" it gets displayed. Set it to `UIWindowLevelStatusBar` to have it cover everything. Set its `hidden` property to NO.
- A 2nd `UIWindow` can be used to bring views on the screen that float on top of everything. Without creating a dummy controller just to embed that in a `UIPopoverController`.
- It can be especially useful on iPhone where there is no popover controller but where you might want to mimic something like it.
- And yes, it solved of course my problem: if the app resigns activation, add a cover window over whatever is currently shown to prevent iOS from taking a screenshot of your app's current content.

Comment: I wouldn't have had the courage to use another UIWindow if not for your answer. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6698102/458193) was also extremely helpful because the second UIWindow wouldn't autorotate on its own.

Comment: Very enlightening post. But what happens if you resign this window and make the underlying window key and visible and this underlying window's rootViewController has a modal controller currently presented? Will it present the modal view controller back? What happens in our application is that rootViewController is presented not the modal one...

Comment: @Krumelur This is fine. I have a doubt. It is, say the 2nd UIWindow is displayed on top of all the current views. When the user clicks one button on the view which is in 1st UIWindow which is presenting one more viewcontroller. This 2nd UIWindow would hide. How to make this UIWindow to be displayed always throughout the whole app.

Comment: I use UIWindow all the time for implementing custom styled alert views and iphone popovers. It helps always making the view fullscreen, containing a fullscreen view and embedding another "content"-view inside so the outer view will catch any touch events (and so i can add a nice shadow and dim my other content ^^)

Comment: It should be noted that a second window is not retained just for being visible (in contrast with regular views being retained by their superview).

Comment: In my experience I didn't want the new window to become the keyWindow because its purpose was just to show an overlay that the user should not be able to touch. Having this non-key overlay window caused some problems back in the time of iOS5~iOS6 when apple introduced the dictionary model view controller that appears when tapping on "define" when a word is selected in a text view.

Comment: I don't know if the problem still exists now but in iOS5 iOS6 dismissing the dictionary view controller made my application irresponsive. It was still alive but not receiving events. Non of my windows received events. So I ended up by creating my overlay view in the first window :(

Comment: I wish at that time documentation was better and tell what is the effect of having a non-key window on top of key window. -- I don't know the answer even now BTW

Comment: third bullet point seems incorrect. I created two windows with rootViewController having textfields but one of the window was initWithFrame where frame was inset of the main screen bounds. Toggled the key windows and found that both the textfeids can be edited.

Answer (score 0):

Here is **Apple's Documentation** for better understanding UIWindow:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/WindowScreenRolesinApp/WindowScreenRolesinApp.html

One good though specific reason to use multiple instances of UIWindow is when you need to video record the app screen. You may not want to include certain elements (recording button, recording status, etc.) in the final recorded video, so you can put those elements in a separate UIWindow on top.

In fact, if you are using ReplayKit, you will *have to* use a separate UIWindow for these excluded UI elements. More info here: https://medium.com/ar-tips-and-tricks/how-to-record-a-screen-capture-with-replaykit-whilst-hiding-the-hud-element-bedcca8e31e