# Multiple UIWindow vs single UIWindow

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwindow

I would like to get some information about UIWindow, particularly multiple UIWindow in a single iOS application. I understand that virtual keyboard is a another UIWindow.

Is there any drawback on using multiple UIWindow vs swapping self.view in a single UIWindows?

What are the implication to hit-testing, ui composition, calayer etc?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232398/advantages-problems-examples-of-adding-another-uiwindow-to-an-ios-app

It has some good info on UIWindow.