# Creating new UIWindows, taking over key window -- bad practice?

Tags: ios, overlay, uiwindow, keywindow

I'm working on an app which needs to display an overlay an top of everything else. It does this by creating a new UIWindow, and using makeKeyAndVisble to "take over" the screen. When it's done, it gives control back back to the original UIWindow.

Is this a bad thing to do?  It feels like it's taking control of the app at a low level, which is generally bad;  on the other hand, it's very straightforward to do, so maybe it's perfectly acceptable.

Opinions/experiences?

Comment: FLEX uses another UIWindow https://github.com/Flipboard/FLEX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience it is perfectly fine to add another `UIWindow` on top of the default one.

I also do not think that this is like taking control of the app at a low level. If I consider that the iOS SDK is closely related to the MacOS SDK, I tend to think that multiple window are perfectly supported at a higher level of abstraction: it is only that on iOS they are not so necessary or useful (generally speaking, apart from specific cases).

Digging a bit on the web, I found this [interesting discussion on S.O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232398/advantages-problems-examples-of-adding-another-uiwindow-to-an-ios-app).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link -- that's exactly what I was trying to ask! :-)