# Adding UIView on top of all views dynamically during runtime?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

Team,

I am trying to bring a menu in top of all visible views during runtime. This menu should be easily addable and removable dynamically in certain conditions.

To do this, I have tried adding a button view to the UIWindow as a subview during runtime.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[window addSubview:button];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
[window bringSubviewToFront:button];
```

But it doesnt worked. Also I have tried to place this button in the root view controller, but no luck again.

**Edit - Note:** This code is not from a `UIViewController`. I am trying to build a library this will be in that library code. Use case be like you could post NSNotification to enable and disable this menu dynamically during runtime.

Please suggest.

Thanks !

Comment: you can add button after navigation i.e. when you navigate to you initial view controller after that add you code in view did load of initial view controller

Comment: @Kalpesh I dont want to add this in UIViewController

Comment: You can add this in window from initial view controller.. create a method in appdelgate , add your code in this method  and call this method from intital view controller

Comment: @Kalpesh Do you mean rootviewcontroller. Could you please give some code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would be add the menu view to the controller's view. You will have some benefits:

1. It will handle rotation correctly
2. You do not mess with window

Taking a look to your code, I should suppose that you are using it inside a view controller, thus you do not need to call [window makeKeyAndVisible]. Also, you are not showing which window you are talking about. Are you creating it? are you using the one of your root view controller?

Comment: I have edited my question. The code is not in UIViewController. I am talking main window.

Answer (score 0):

in appdelgate.h

```
-(void)addMarketOpenCloseIcon;
```

in appdelgate.m

```
#pragma mark Add Market Open Close Label

-(void)addMarketOpenCloseIcon

    if (lblMarketOpenClose==nil) {
        lblMarketOpenClose=[[UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(116,20, 80, 21)];
        lblMarketOpenClose.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
        [lblMarketOpenClose setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        lblMarketOpenClose.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12];
        [self.window addSubview:lblMarketOpenClose];
    }
} 

#pragma mark DidFinishLauch
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    //create all table
    LoginViewController *login=[[LoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
        navigationController        = [[ UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:login];

    [self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

In LoginViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   appdelgate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
   [appdelgate addMarketOpenCloseIcon];
}
```

Comment: This code works, But when I make the rootViewController as the login it doesnt works, that is if the rootViewController is the UIViewController its not working. Its working only if the rootViewController is UINavigationController. Any reason behind it? I am looking for a solution which works for all?

Answer (score 0):

You want to display something that floats over all of the user's views.  You want to implement this in a library to be used generically.

That sounds a lot like a `UIAlertView`.  Why not implement it the same way as `UIAlertView`?  Create a new `UIWindow` and set its `windowLevel` to `UIWindowLevelAlert`.  Put your “floating” content in your own `UIWindow`.

You can find some useful tips for creating a second `UIWindow` in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8232398/77567).

Comment: I need to be able to interact with both the windows. Is it possible.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  It should be easy if you make the floating window smaller than full-screen.

Answer (score -1):

Create UIWindow object, add the button on it and then add the UIWindow object into    [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;   
UIWindow *buttonWindow = [UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.bounds]  

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];                            
[button addTarget:self action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];   
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];   
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);   

[buttonWindow addSubview: button];
[keyWindow addSubview: buttonWindow]

[buttonWindow makeKeyAndVisible]  

[backgroundWindow bringSubviewToFront:button];
```

Comment: @Idindu What is backgroundWindow here?

Comment: backroundWindow is buttonWindow which contains button.