# iOS: How to add a floating button in a new non-key custom window?

Tags: ios, objective-c, window, uikit

I've read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8232398/1677041) about custom window in iOS. Here it is, I create a new window and show it via `window.hidden = NO;` above the key window, the final goal is to make the custom window transparent and the `btnAction` within it could receive events.

If I set the window's `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO`, all the events sending to subviews of it will go through to the next lower level window (it's the key window here). If I disable the `userInteractionEnabled` line and leave it to `YES` defaultly, the custom window will suppress all the events with `do nothing` in the transparent area, but the `btnAction` will receive my expected event.

I know there is a way to let the custom window bypass the events from specified transparent area, just inherit the `UIWindow` to create a new subclass window and override these methods to achieve it.

```
// From UIView.h
- (nullable UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(nullable UIEvent *)event;   // recursively calls -pointInside:withEvent:. point is in the receiver's coordinate system
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(nullable UIEvent *)event;   // default returns YES if point is in bounds
```

**I just wonder that are there any other quick easy ways to fix that without inheriting?**

```
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelNormal + 1;
    window.userInteractionEnabled = NO; // This will block the events which send to `btnAction`, too.
    // window.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4];
    window.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;

    UIButton *btnAction = [UIButton new];
    [btnAction setBackgroundImage:UIImageFromColor(RandomColor) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnAction addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [window addSubview:btnAction];

    [btnAction mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.width.height.equalTo(@60);
        make.right.equalTo(window).offset(-20);
        make.bottom.equalTo(window).offset(-60);
    }];
```

Comment: I suppose you could swizzle those methods.  See [this NSHipster article](https://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/).  Maybe someone wants to post an example of how to swizzle this as an answer.

Comment: Swizzling the classes from the system framework will cause unexpected behaviors, I don't think that is a good idea.  @Smartcat

Comment: Heh, you asked for quick and easy, but didn't include "safe". :P  But yes, you're correct.  Just giving you an alternative.

Comment: Also, I suspect a swizzle expert could do it safely - but the rest of us should avoid it in production code.